# Extremely frustrating behavior with Internet Explorer, Bootstrap and Respond.js

Tags: php, jquery, html, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to rewrite my unfinished site http://mirai.ca in the Racket programming language rather than PHP, which I had started to rather dislike. The problem is that I can't just copy-and-paste HTML; Racket uses S-expressions to represent XML and I must use them to build my site. The syntax should be an easy translation, but Racket's not the point here.

Rather, it is IE 8 support. This is getting me crazy. http://mirai.ca works absolutely *fine* in IE 8, with `respond.js` handling CSS3 responsive design, etc etc. Now http://staging.mirai.ca, which *should* be a straightforward translation of the first half of the page (minus some fancy CSS) into Sexps, **just doesn't work**. IE 8 refuses to do responsive resizing.

The outputted HTML on both sites are basically human-readable, one just needs to run them through a beautifier or something. I just cannot find the difference leading to the different behavior! This is soooo frustrating, and I've already spent like 4 hours scratching my head over this.

Answer (score 2):

> Racket uses S-expressions to represent XML and I must use them to
>   build my site.

Have you looked at templates?

http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/templates.html?q=template

Comment: Umm. `Racket's not the point here`. Ignore everything about Racket - this is a question about HTML as far as people should be concerned.

Comment: @EricDong you haven't even tagged the question as HTML